# Send data from iphone app to mac desktop app

Tags: iphone

I have an iphone app that when touching a button should push a text to a mac desktop app. On that mac app when touching a button (or instantly) it should show that text.

What steps would be invloved in this? I mean the networking part.

Any tutorials you can share?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure why this was downvoted. The question may be far-reaching, but it is clear and concise and I wouldn't classify it as a "Send Me Teh Codez" request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to have a look at [ZSync](http://www.zarrastudios.com/ZSync/ZSync.html). It's an open source framework designed to do exactly this.

Comment: Thanks Ben, i downloaded it but i can't find any info on how to use it.
I am running the desktop demo, the touch demo and the daemon but syncing on either end does not do anything.

Comment: I would contact them for support; I'm just the messenger here :-)